# Jquery Animation Not working in switchClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is my jquery,

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

    $(this).parent().find(".plusminus").switchClass('glyphicon-plus', 'glyphicon-minus', 1000, 'easeInQuad');
    $(this).parent().find(".plusminus").css("color", "");

    $(this).parent().find(".panel-heading").addClass('select');
});
$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.plusminus').switchClass('glyphicon-minus', 'glyphicon-plus', 1000, 'easeInQuad');
    $(this).parent().find(".plusminus").css("color", "#FF7E00");
    $(this).parent().find(".panel-heading").removeClass('select');
});
```

this is my html which i have used,

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a class="linkfaq" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <i class="plusminus glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-left" style="color: #FF7E00"></i>
                    <?php echo $p[ 'question'] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" class="collapse">
            <?php echo $p[ 'answer']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here, as shown in code i have used switchClass but animation not working.

Comment: html please or fiddle

Comment: i have include this one `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `jquery.ui.widget.js` this one as well

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: make a demo on jsbin, share here the link and we will test there.